# Boost smart array is not working

Tags: linux, boost, shared-ptr

I have a code which compiles properly with Boost 1.49. i upgraded boost to 1.61 and now i am facing error like:

> error: no matching function for call to boost::shared_array::shared_array(unsigned char)
>   Boost/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:56: note: candidates are: boost::shared_array::shared_array() [with T = unsigned char]
>   Boost/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:45: note:                 boost::shared_array::shared_array(const boost::shared_array&)

Code snippate is like

```
boost::shared_array<uint8_t> val;
constructor():val(0){}
```

what might be the possible solution for this?

My current set up is on a linux machine with GCC version 4.1.

Comment: What linux environment are you running that contains an ancient version of GCC? [4.1 is nearly 10 years old (February 13, 2007)](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade compilers. 4.1 is not supported by any recent version of boost.

The snippet is no problem on supported combinations:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb46c582e09ed1be)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp>

struct x {
    boost::shared_array<uint8_t> val;
    x() : val(0) {}
};

int main() {
    x x;
}
```

From the [supported compilers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html#log.installation.supported_compilers) page:

> Linux. GCC 4.5 and newer. Older versions may work too, but it was not tested.

And

> The following compilers/platforms are not supported and will likely fail to compile the library:
>
> ...
>
> - GCC 4.2 and older.

Comment: Thanx @sehe. I was suspected the GCC version might be the problem. Is it ok if I change that specific part of shared_array.hpp where multiple constructors are implemented to have only 1 definition?